# Where to check for node value constraints on services data receive

Tags: 7, hooks, services

I have a REST service to create nodes. On data receive, `node.create` is executed, but before actually creating the node I need to check some constraints like *node type* and other node values.

Is there any I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have more control on the node creation you need to write up your own service for nodes using  `hook_services_resources()`. By default you can control only the access for creating a particular node using permissions.

If you need to control node creation via node values, you need to go with your own services.